# How do you select in-line text with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I select the text infront of the unordered list below?

```
<li class="foo">
   How can I remove this text?
   <ul class="bar">
       <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
$('ul.bar').previousSibling().remove();
```

But I think that would only work with another element, and I'm not entirely sure how to go about selecting text that isn't contained inside tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the solution you're looking for.

```
$('.foo').contents().filter(function(){
    return (this.nodeType == 3);
}).remove();
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/mLxsrfwa/)

> The nodeType property returns the node type, as a number, of the
>   specified node.
>   If the node is a text node, the nodeType property will return 3.

---

Non jQuery version:

Get the Parent Node. Get all the Children nodes of the Parent. Convert the collection of Nodes to an array. Loop through the array. Check the nodeType on every iteration. If the `nodeType === 3` then it's a text node. Then delete it.

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById('parent_node_id_here').childNodes, 0).forEach(function (value) {
    if (value.nodeType === 3) {
        value.remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Good one! I was going to hack it with: `$('.foo').html($('.bar'));`  But your  answer is exactly what he's asking for

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".foo").contents().get(0).remove()
```

or without jquery

```
document.getElementsByClassName("foo")[0].childNodes[0].remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".foo").replaceWith($.parseHTML($(".foo").html()).slice(1));
```

```js
$(".foo").replaceWith($.parseHTML($(".foo").html()).slice(1));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="foo">
   How can I remove this text?
   <ul class="bar">
       <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```